# Parallel RNG with JAX sharding

Tags: python, random, parallel-processing, jax

What is the correct approach for generating pseudo random numbers in parallel using sharding in `jax`?

The following doesn't work (due to sampling the same chain)

```
sharding = jax.sharding.PositionalSharding(
    jax.experimental.mesh_utils.create_device_mesh((8,)),
)

@jax.jit(static_argnum=1, out_sharding=sharding.reshape(8, 1))
def uniform_sharded(rng_key, n):
    return jax.random.uniform(key=rng_key, shape=(n,))
```

I considered performing a `pmap` across devices with an array of keys, but the output would then be dependent on the device count and would seem to defeat the intent of sharding.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Note that using a PRNG to deterministically generate numbers is highly dangerous, any change in any of the algorithms will come back to haunt you. Let's just say that I would not trust it to generate the same values across versions of the same library.

Comment: The intent was to populate elements of a linear operator for testing, comparing results computed on the host with a multi-device run. Disregarding this use case, is multi-device RNG possible with only sharding? As far as I can tell, explicit collective communication is the only way.